# how to know whether user comes on my site by clicking back button?

Tags: jquery, cookies, browser, document, back-button

I want to detect on my website page load that whether visiting user comes on my website by clicking on the back button of some other site or not?

e.g let's say I opened my website in browser typing http://mysitedomain.com I clicked a link here which takes user to http://yahoo.com now if user clicks on back button he will come to my website but I want to detect this :) there is also possibility that user from yahoo.com clicked on some ad to come to mysite.com in this case I dont want to do anything but only in back button case?

Is that possible to do so? I can detect back button click on my site with **onpopstate** but how do I know user came on my site by clicking back button?

Please help!

Comment: @sradha I am trying with document.referrer but it gives blank when you click on back button also thats not a good idea to know that you coming from back button or from where?

Answer (score 0):

Browser will execute the last HTTP request when you pressed the back button (if the page is not expired, it will load from cache). Further, logic behind the back button may be different depending on which browser client is using. I think there is no common way which will work for all browsers to differentiate back button loading and newly loading page. You may use **cookies**, **request headers** depending on your application need.

Comment: I am not looking for what you said TRiNE. I know that what you saying, I just want to know on page load of my site that here user is coming via back button or via something else.

Comment: @user3110655 That's what I said. "I am not looking for what you said"? I can't find a difference between my argue and your one?